# Minecraft sounds not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

The sounds in Minecraft will not work in any version of MC I have tried. Playing with mods, the mods' sounds will work but not the vanilla sounds. I have tried multiple things including:

- Restarting my computer
- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Using the <kbd>F3</kbd> key method
- Looking at the sound files on my PC
- Making sure MC isn't blocked by an antivirus

Comment: Have you checked the sliders in `Options...` -> `Music & Sounds...`?

Comment: you mean my volume in game yes its at max on all of them

Comment: all in game volume is at max

Comment: also forgot to mention I also previously took the .mc folder and put on my desk top and mc made s[a new folder which I put all the files on the date prior to the day in the new .mc file and kept all items that were the same and I just found legacy.json and a objects folder with a lot of file rather than having a black page thing with no name and that takes no storage at all in it and put those on just now

Comment: I have had this happened to me a few times. To fix it I reload my resource pack via f3+t in game. Not sure if it'll work for you but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: I have done that already read the  paragraph

Comment: Does this only happen in Minecraft, or does it happen in other programs as well?

Comment: no only mine craft

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if the `assets` directory in `.minecraft` has an `indexes` folder containing a JSON file for the version you are trying to play. If not try deleting the `versions` folder to get the launcher to redownload the game. If all else fails try deleting the `assets` directory.

Comment: Also check if the `objects` folder has about 250+ folders in there

Comment: I have jsons and my objects folder has them all

Answer (score -2):

See if your volume in minecraft, on your headphones isn't too low.

Comment: of course its not I have it at max and my speakers are at least at 10-30

Comment: and its at 10 because of loud mod mob sounds that are the mods own sounds so still I hear those

Comment: Do you have updated drivers?